# How do you copy files from one EBS to another?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I'm an EC2 beginner. I was able to setup a working EC2 instance for my site. The problem is that I want to use a different AMI (a CentOS one).

I'm wondering what's the exact way to transfer files from one EBS to another EBS?

To be clear, I've researched online and I see that the best way to do this is to mount the EBS to the new instance, and copy the files then. My problem is that I haven't seen any clear, step-by-step instructions on how to do this.

I'm hoping you guys can give me this, as I don't want to mess up my working EC2 instance by using rsync to sync the files in between it and the new instance. (Unless this is an acceptable way to do it, then by all means please let me know)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For transferring files/folders to Ec2 instance, here are the suggested steps

**Windows to linux**

You can download and install winscp http://download.cnet.com/WinSCP/3000-2160_4-10400769.html, using this application you can transfer the files/folders

**Linux to Windows**

you can execute the following command,

scp -i key_pairfile_location zip_file_name.zip root@machine_name:target_folder

Hope this helps !

Comment: Seems to cover transferring to/from local PC< not between EBS